# MonoRail - How to render view in another area

Tags: castle-monorail

I'm using MonoRail and want to render the same view from two separate areas. I looked at all of the RenderView overloads and none of them have an area parameter, which seems odd to me. As a workaround I could create a user control and have two separate views, but it'd be nice to know if there's a way to call a view in a different area from RenderView.

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC you can pick any view by defining its path, e.g.:

```
RenderView("/area/controller/viewname");
```